# Can't get size of the video in AVPlayerLayer on screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a view with layer(AVPlayerLayer) that contains video player(AVPlayer).

I used code from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1) to show video on the screen.

```
@implementation PlayerView
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}
- (AVPlayer*)player {
    return [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] player];
}
- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player {
    [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
}
@end
```

How i can get size of the video in playerview.frame? 
I can't use *videoGravity* for fill entire frame of the view, because i need to display landscape and portrait video.

Comment: I'm not sure which size do you want to get. The actual video size (video frame dimensions)? The portion of player layer with video content?

Comment: I want to get video frame in AVPlayerLayer after scaling/resizing of PlayerView. Not actual video size.

Comment: [self layer].frame.size?

Comment: It gives to you layer size, but not size of resized video in that layer.

I found answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113468/1545158

Comment: yeah this works: GRect transformedBounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform([avplayerLayer bounds], CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(playerLayer.sublayerTransform));

Answer (score 2):

You can use `videoRect` property of the `AVPlayerLayer`. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerLayer_Class/).

Answer (score 0):

### 2022 SwiftUI Approach

```
struct PlayerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    private let avController =  AVPlayerViewController()
    var videoURL: URL?
    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    }
    
    //  HERE 
    func getVideoActualSize() -> CGRect {
        self.avController.videoBounds
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        avController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        avController.player = player
        avController.player?.play()
        return avController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```